# JPA (openjpa), DB2, update, commit = Invalid cursor name?

Tags: jpa, db2, websphere, openjpa, sqlexception

Trying to perform a simple update on an object with JPA (WebSphere-openjpa, DB2):

```
public T update(T t) {
    synchronized(this) {
        this.em.getTransaction().begin();
        t = this.em.merge(t);
        this.em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    return t;
}
```

But getting "Invalid cursor name" SQL exception during transaction commit. Any ideas what this means?

```
[3/07/12 12:17:27:586 EST] 00000025 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[JAXRSApplication]: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1179900 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.RollbackException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: prepstmnt 125018062 UPDATE CCHDEVT.TCC_PROPERTY SET COMMENTS = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = ? [org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement_]
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:593)
at com.qbe.config.dao.GenericDAOJpaImpl.update(GenericDAOJpaImpl.java:50)
at com.qbe.config.service.QBEPropertyService.saveProperty(QBEPropertyService.java:42)
at com.qbe.config.web.QBEPropertyResource.save(QBEPropertyResource.java:87)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$VoidOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:167)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:763)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3703)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
```

breaking it up...

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1179900 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
FailedObject: prepstmnt 125018062 UPDATE CCHDEVT.TCC_PROPERTY SET COMMENTS = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = ? [org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement_]
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2321)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2158)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2056)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1974)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.LocalManagedRuntime.commit(LocalManagedRuntime.java:81)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.commit(BrokerImpl.java:1498)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.commit(DelegatingBroker.java:933)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.commit(EntityManagerImpl.java:569)
... 45 more
```

breaking it up...

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1179900 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid cursor name.
FailedObject: prepstmnt 125018062 UPDATE CCHDEVT.TCC_PROPERTY SET COMMENTS = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? WHERE PROPERTY_NAME = ? [org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager$CancelPreparedStatement_]
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4878)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4838)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.newStoreException(DB2Dictionary.java:596)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:78)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushBatch(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:236)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:63)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:103)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:76)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:742)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
... 52 more
```

breaking it up...

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.SqlException: Invalid cursor name.
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.zc.setCursorName(zc.java:723)
at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper.doStatementCleanup(DB2UniversalDataStoreHelper.java:243)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:490)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJccPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJccPreparedStatement.java:294)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:240)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:193)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.close(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:161)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.close(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:161)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushBatch(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:234)
... 57 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: It's quite huge but here it is.. :)

Comment: Thanks. What is your setting for resultSetHoldability ?

Comment: It was set to 2, I've set it to 1 (and restarted the server) and still getting the same error so probably not that but good to know about resultSetHoldability, didn't know about it..